# Pressing super+right-arrow results in tty3 login prompt

Tags: 16.04, gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, tty

This has been happening to on my machine a lot lately. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> is how I position windows using the GNome Put Windows extension. Pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> results in a black screen on both monitors with a tty3 login prompt on one monitor.

> Rebooting solves the problem for a few hours
>
> Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> to restart the desktop environment does not help.

Haven't been able to find any information about his problem. Perhaps I'm asking the question wrong.

Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS 64-bit, GNOME Shell 3.18.5

Comment: If the keyboard shortcut behaves as intended for a while and then ceases to do so, could you please verify that the GNOME Shell extension in question is still enabled and working? I've had such extensions disabled in the past when they crashed. Another option is to look at the extension's error log in [Looking Glass](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/LookingGlass) or the session log file (`~/.cache/gdm/session.log` for GDM, `~/.xsession-errors` for most other display managers including LightDM).

Comment: @DavidFoerster that is very helpful information. I'm sure I'll have the problem again later today and will look at Looking Class. I looked in both locations you suggest for the error log and neither the /gdm nor /.xsession-errors folders exist. Does this mean there is no error log or is there another location?

Comment: It's not `/.xsession-errors` but `~/.xsession-errors`. The leading `~` is a shorthand for the current user's home directory in Bash an similar shell command interpreters. Same with `~/.cache/gdm/session.log`. Did you omit that while looking up the files or was that just a typo in your comment?

Comment: @DavidFoerster - apologies, I left the ~ off. There is no ~/.xsession-errors on my machine

Comment: This was driving me nuts for a month or so before I asked the question. However, the machine has been up for 9 days since and no re-occurrence. But I think the most likely possibility is that the extension was crashing.